# Clashing of id in jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector

I am currently trying to do edit and update table using AJAX and jquery. The table structure would be the **title** linked to many **criteria** while they link through the **title_id**. However when I'm going to add a new criteria under a title, I find out that the jquery selector will select other blank criteria field which share the same ID and thus will keep alert about blank field. Is there anyway to specifically point the exact cell to be added?

(*There are specific data attributes for each criteria which are pointing to the relevant title which is like below:* )

Row details:

```
<tr><td rowspan="'.$rowspan.'" class="title" data-title-id="'.$titleID.'" 
contenteditable>'.$titleDesc.'</td>
<td id="criteriaDesc" data-title-id="'.$titleID.'" contenteditable></td>
<td><button type="btn_add" id="btn_add_crit" data-title-id="'.$titleID.'" class="btn btn-md btn-success" title="Add criteria">+</button></td></tr>
```

jquery code:

```
        $(document).on('click','#btn_add_crit',function(){
        var criteria = $('#criteriaDesc').text();
        var titleID = $(this).data('title-id');
        if(criteria == '')
        {
            alert("The text is "+criteria);
            return false;
        }               

        $.ajax({
            url:"critInsert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{criteria:criteria,titleID:titleID},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                fetch_data();
            }
        })
    });
```

The table:

[image]

Tried my best to explain my problem and looking for helps!

Comment: “*…other blank criteria field which share the same ID*” - and that, right there, is your problem: don’t use the same `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas but what if i need to because the rows are generated through a loop? Or do i have to find another way?

Comment: Use class not ID....ID's are unique in a page by definition

Comment: @charlietfl if i use class will the jquery still select all same class field?

Comment: Yes `$('.someClassName')` selects all of that class in the page

Comment: @charlietfl But my objective is to select only the filled in field other than the field which share the same class/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get the `criteriaDesc` value from the cell, corresponding to clicked '+' button.

```
$(".btn_add_crit").click(function() {
  console.log($($(this).parents()[1]).find(".criteriaDesc").text());
});
```

As you can see from the code above. you can and **need** to change your duplicate ids to be classes.

First of all you need to understand that **all IDs must be unique**. If you ignore this, your markup will be still loaded fine, but code will not work. Both jQuery (as well as other JS libs) and pure JS are not able to select 2nd, 3rd and so on element with same ID, because they hardly believe, that there can be only one.

And second. You should study a little more about how jQuery works. If you have a lot of buttons and corresponding text fields, you can't just write selector for all those fields and hope that the correct one will be selected. In my answer the connection between button and text field is reached with `parents()` function for example.

Comment: Hi actually i solved my problems by changing the id's into class name with unique class name combination with such `'<td class = "criteriaDesc"'.$titleID.' contenteditable></td>` and taking the specific field name each time the button was clicked. Thanks for the answer anyway!